# A special character

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

You and your friends are playing a computer game (numpad to move!) and need to unlock a special character! To do so, the game has given you a clue and a dialog box to enter the codeword. If you get the codeword correct, you unlock the character!

`Clue: 7419635 14789523 14789635 74123`

`Enter Codeword Here: ________________`

What's the codeword and what does the special character do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The codeword is

> HEAL

Reason:

> Using the numpad, draw a line through the given numbers. It spells out the letters.

Comment: No way; 8 minutes. Correct, though! :):)

Comment: And I guess it's obvious to say you know what the character does. (It's a healer.)